# How to get a string value from a ASPxComboBox in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to extract the selected value from a a `DropDownList` as a `string` as follows:

```
if ((ASPxComboBox1.SelectedItem.Value).ToString = "Selection")
```

This is not working.  Please let me know if there is a away of getting each selected string extracted?

Comment: Well probably the question is not too clear, Anyways will do
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax seems odd but try (I am assuming c# because you didn't specify the language your using):

```
if (ASPxComboBox1.SelectedValue.Equals("Selection"))
```

In your code you are doing an assignment and assigning the text "Selection" to `ToString` which shouldn't even compile.

Also you named it a combobox but ASP.NET does not have a combobox just a dropdownlist...

Comment: Thx,
Im new to ASP.net,so trying these for the first time.I was able to get there working through your solution.

Comment: How do I accepet a answer please? When I try to click the answer is useful it always ask for the openID ,eventhough I am already logged in.So end up not doing anything to the answer.
Thanks for ur comments

Comment: @LS trying logging out and back in. Then you can just click the checkmark next to the answer you want to be the accepted answer. If it still doesn't work you might want to report a bug on http://meta.stackoverflow.com